# How optimizing javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

Is there another way to rewrite this code to be more optimized, because i see that it's very repetitive in the `mousemove` action, also `if` condition

```
    if (dept === "Parlement européen") {
        var popup_topo = $("<div class='popup_topo'><strong>" + dep + "<br/>" + total + " parrainages</strong></div>");
        $(this).on("mousemove", function (event) {
          if ($(window).width() < 480) {
            var x = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left - 45;
            var y = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top + 30;
          } else if ($(window).width() > 480) {
            var x = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left + 30;
            var y = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top + 30;
          }
          $(this).append(popup_topo);
          popup_topo.css({
            top: `${y}px`,
            left: `${x}px`,
          });
        })
        .on("mouseleave", function (event) {
          popup_topo.remove();
        });
      }
      else {
        var popup_topo = $("<div class='popup_topo'><strong>" + dept + "<br/>" + total + " parrainages</strong></div>");
        $(this).on("mousemove", function (event) {
          if ($(window).width() < 480) {
            var x = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left - 45;
            var y = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top + 30;
          } else if ($(window).width() > 480) {
            var x = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left + 30;
            var y = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top + 30;
          }

          $(this).append(popup_topo);
          popup_topo.css({
            top: `${y}px`,
            left: `${x}px`,
          });
        })
        .on("mouseleave", function (event) {
          popup_topo.remove();
        });
     }
```

Comment: What is the actual _difference_ between the two to begin with? Nearly everything appears identical, expect your popup content - you used `dep` in the first one, `dept` in the second, although currently I can't tell whether that's on purpose, or a typo.

Comment: "repetitive" is an understatement. These two branches of the topmost `if` are exactly the same. https://www.diffchecker.com/0igrOb5U (save for dep/dept typo). So you can remove the topmost condition and leave only one of the branches, eliminating all of the duplication.

Comment: my code is working, i just wanted to know if we could optimize it further...

Comment: If this isn't a typo, you can remove one branch and replace the first line with `var popup_topo = $(\`<div class='popup_topo'><strong>${dept === "Parlement européen" ? dep : dept}<br/>${total} parrainages</strong></div>\`);` Result: https://jsfiddle.net/thx3gvqr/

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of simple suggestions:

1. The `mousemove` event (at least the vanilla version, and I'm assuming jQuery's is similar) gets called quite frequently. You could set a minimum time between iterations if you want to process considerably less code.
2. You use the same definition for `y` in two places; you can define it just once, outside the conditional block.
3. As commenters have mentioned, your outer conditional statement should probably be removed entirely.

(Note: You probably don't need or want to include `if ($(window).width() > 480)` -- unless you have a reason to treat a width of exactly 480 as a special case with no format specified.)